# Conditional styled components effect all instances when nested

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

If i use a prop condition on the main component it will work per instance.

So for example if i have:

```
const Div = styled.div<Props>`
  ${(props) => {
    return css`
      ${props.test && "border: 5px solid red;"};


    `;
  }}
`;
```

only components which have the `test` prop will have this ugly border :)

But if i use this same condition on a nested css rule like that:

```
const Div = styled.div<Props>`
  ${(props) => {
    return css`
      .tabletScreen & {
        ${props.test && "border: 5px solid red;"};
      }
    `;
  }}
`;
```

All instances of this component will have this ugly border if one of the components has this `test` prop.

When inspect it i see that all instances of the component gets the same class generated, so the this:

```
.tabletScreen .sc-jcFjpl {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Is implemented to all instances.

But on the first case (when the condition is not nested) the component with the `test` prop will get another class so it won't override the others.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use && instead of & and it'll be scoped to that stylistic instance of the component. Single ampersand refers to the "static component class".

More info here: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting